# Why is import statement not needed in this instance?

Tags: java

Why does Java allow me to exclude the import statement for `MyClass` in the following case.   Also there must not be any other explicit declarations of MyClass in the rest of the class.  It seems like javac should not allow the import to be missing.

```
public class MyClassDao {
     public List<MyClass> getAll(){....}
}


// no import needed here for MyClass
public class RandomService {
    ....
    void process(){
        myModel.setMyClassList(myClassDao.getAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: if it is in the same package then you don't need to import it

Comment: @donfuxx What if it isn't in the same package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As the Java Language Specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5)

> An import declaration allows a named type or a static member to be
>   referred to by a simple name (§6.2) that consists of a single
>   identifier.

You are not referring to the name `MyClass`, so no `import` statement is needed.